# Ever heard of a snapped rear gear sprocket?

Tags: road-bike, gears, cassette, sprocket

Has anyone come across a rear gear sprocket snapping before? A clean break straight across the diameter. Happened at bottom of hill but not excessive force by any means.

Not new but not terribly old either, used mostly for commuting, as far as I can tell otherwise in good condition.

Unfortunately the subsequent fall resulted in broken elbow and wrist...

Is there anything that might have caused/contributed to this? Should I follow up with manufacturer?

Comment: Sorry to hear you were injured. Are you willing to reveal the manufacturer and model? Can you add a picture?

Comment: Hi David - yes fair enough. It seemed an unusual break and was intrigued if anyone heard of similar. I was wondering what might have caused/contributed to this or if i should follow up with manufacturer. Have edited to make clearer. Thanks,

Comment: http://pardo.net/bike/pic/fail-002/000.html has impressive collection of failed bicycle parts, including some sprocets. Depending on where you live, the manufacturer or seller may have some responsibility even if the warranty period is over.

Comment: @Scott Thanks for the edit -- seems much more concrete, now.

Comment: This would almost certainly be the result of some sort of manufacturing defect.

Comment: Adding a couple of clear well-lit photos of the damaged part may help.